# Solve $|z|=\arg z$

Tags: complex-numbers

Im trying to find all set of points on the complex plane for which $|z|=\arg z$.

I rewrote $|z|= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\arg z$ as $\tan^{-1}(y/x)$.I set them equal But im not sure what to do next.

Comment: When you set (when $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$):

$$\arg\left(\text{z}\right)=\arg\left(\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{\Im\left[\text{z}\right]}{\Re\left[\text{z}\right]}\right)$$

That is only true when $\Re\left[\text{z}\right]>0$ and $\Im\left[\text{z}\right]>0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interpret ${\rm arg}$ as principal value ${\rm Arg}$, and write $z$ in the form $$z=r(\cos\theta+i \sin\theta)\qquad(r\geq0,\quad -\pi<\theta<\pi)\ .$$
Your condition then amounts to $$r=\theta\ ,$$
so that necessarily $r=\theta>0$, since $\theta$ is undefined at $z=0$. This shows that the set
$$S:=\bigl\{z=\theta\,(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\in{\mathbb C}\>\bigm|0< \theta<\pi\bigr\}\ ,$$
an arc 
[image]
of an Archimedean spiral
[image]

is the solution to your problem.

Comment: A picture would be a great addition

Answer (score 0):

Let $|z|=\arg z=t$. Then by definition

$$z=|z|e^{i\arg z}=te^{it},$$

(in Cartesian coordinates $x=t\cos t,y=t\sin t$) which is an Archimedean spiral .