# How would you plot $|z|=\operatorname{arg}(z)$ on an argand diagram?

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

Is there an easy way to see how to plot $|z|=\operatorname{arg}(z)$ on an argand diagram? Replacing the modulus and argument with the cartesian counterpart seems to be needlessly obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just plot $$z=\theta(\cos\theta+i\cdot\sin\theta)$$
The typical form is $z=r(\cos\theta+i\cdot\sin\theta)$ but given $|z|=r$ and $arg(z)=\theta$, for your case $r=\theta$

Answer (score 0):

It was already often discussed here.
See [Solve $|z|=\arg z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952356/solve-z-arg-z)